# Generating combinations with PHP

Tags: php, combinatorics

So I have the following characters (alt symbols):

```
¯ ˜ ” “ ’ ‘ ¨ ´ ¹ ² ³ ` ° ⁿ
```

What I'm trying to do is simple: generate all possible combinations between them up to the length of two. That being said, few sample generations would look like so:

`¯ ^ ¨`
`³ ^ “`

Also they need be seperated by let's say the XOR operator. I was thinking about the following scenario:

```
$array = array('¯', '˜' ,'”', '“', '’', '‘', '¨', '´', '¹', '²', '³', '`', '°', 'ⁿ');

foreach ($array as $element) {
    echo $element ' ^ ' //..;
}
```

I just can't actualize my logic. How can I group them in pairs of two elements and go over each possible combination between them without duplicates?

EDIT:

---

Though I managed to get it working with regular letters like so:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', '65');

$values = 'ABCD';
container(strlen($values), 0 );

function container($length, $pos, $out = '' ){
    global $values;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i){
  if ($pos < $length ){
    container($length, $pos + 1, $out . $values[$i]);
  }
    }

    if(strlen($out) <= 2){
  echo $out . '<br />';
  }
}

?>
```

I am ending in a deadlock when using the alt symbols as the values for the iteration.

Comment: is `¯ ^ ¨` considered a dupe of `¨ ^ ¯`?

Comment: Yes actually. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: then a simple nested loop will do. `for($i = 0; $i < count($arr)) { for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($arr)) { ... }}` `i` loop goes over every character, `$j` loop goes over all the chars to the RIGHT of where the `i` loop is. just need to fiddle the termination conditions so that you don't run off the end of the array.

Comment: Updated OP + sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Using some different chars:

```
$chars = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($chars) - 1); $i++) {   // count()-1 to prevent f^f
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($chars); $j++) {  // $i+1 to prevent a^a 
        echo "$chars[$i] ^ $chars[$j]\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a ^ b
a ^ c
a ^ d
a ^ e
a ^ f
b ^ c
b ^ d
b ^ e
b ^ f
c ^ d
c ^ e
c ^ f
d ^ e
d ^ f
e ^ f
```

This is presuming that `a ^ a` is a dupe, and `b^a` and `a^b` are dupes of each other.

Comment: Works perfect for me but can I somehow eval() the output? Because I actually need it non-semantic and get the XOR of the characters.

Comment: then don't use string operations. `$result = $chars[$i] ^ $chars[$j];`